# Draggable, Resizeable, HTML, Saving States

Tags: jquery

I have html elements (video, iframe, image) that are draggable and resizable.  They are added via droppable.  Each one of these elements has a container div (#videoContainer1, #imageContainer1, etc)

Anyone have any ideas on how to *save the states of **each element*** the user has added (html, positioning) into something that's lightweight?

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage if its a modern browser (IE9, latest chrome,safari, ff)

then you can just store any javaScript object in there you wish with possible dimensions/containerId etc.

If you need to support older browsers A cookie would probably suffice since it wont be alot of information but the disadvantage is cookies are sent with each request